# Can't overwrite !important tag (tried several tips already)

Tags: css, tags, overwrite, css-specificity

I'm having trouble overwriting an *!important* tag for `background-color` and `color`. Here's what I'm given:

[Chrome Inspect screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lQfRl.png)

The native greens already seem to be overwriten but I need a different color. If I add my custom CSS the ways I read in this forum, it's not getting the high enough specificity, apparently. Could someone correct me, please?

```
.ccb-wrapper-148669 .calc-buttons .calc-btn-action {
    background: #8c76af !important;
    color: #000 !important;
}
```

I tried changing specificity and using a Javascript snippet but obviously, a wrong way...

Comment: Pretty hard for us to debug a screenshot of your inspector. Edit your question to add a [snack snippet](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/358992/2518285) which demonstrates the problem. Have you read the entirety of this description of [how specificity is calculated](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Specificity)?

Answer (score -1):

From the screenshot you've shared,  it seems the selectors you're using might not be targeting the right element to change the existing styles.

Answer (score -1):

To increase the specificity of your CSS selector and override the existing styles, you can try adding additional parent selectors or class names to target the desired elements.

```
body .ccb-wrapper-148669 .calc-buttons .calc-btn-action {
    background: #8c76af !important;
    color: #000 !important;
}
```

In this example, body is added as a parent selector to increase specificity. If that doesn't work, you can try adding more parent selectors or class names based on the structure of the html.

Comment: Thank you, I tried the approach of adding parent selectors and class names before, and tried body but it didn't help. I'll see if I can hire someone to look closely into it. I appreciate your help, anyway!